# jsPDF.AcroForm TextField new line ignored until clicked on textField of the pdf

Tags: jspdf

Using Mr. Rio's pdf generation library as an example for demonstration at https://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/#
So basically if you copy the code below and paste in the link above you will be able to see what I am talking about. I am attaching the screenshot as well for clarity.

On the sample text myTxt I've two new line so I expect bullet#2 and #3 on new line but it all gets displayed in one line until I click on the textfield and then it recognizes the newline. Is there any solution to this issue or any workarounds?

I've tried using `\r\n`, `\n` and `\u000a` but none of it seems to work.

```
var { TextField } = jsPDF.AcroForm;

doc.setFontSize(20);

var myTxt = `1. This is my first bullet \
            \n2. This is my second bullet \
            \n3.A third one`;
doc.text("TextField:", 10, 145);
var textField = new TextField();
textField.Rect = [50, 140, 150, 60];
textField.multiline = true;
textField.value = myTxt;
doc.addField(textField);
```

[image]
[image]